# How to change search engine in Microsoft edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

Want to change the search engine but the only option is Bing. Please help remove Bing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Microsoft Edge (legacy) works is, it discovers search engines when you visit a search engine website. To see Google in your search engines list, you need to visit Google.com once.

Open Google search engine (e.g., `Google.com`, `Google.co.uk`)   in Microsoft Edge.

Go back to the Advanced Settings in Microsoft Edge. You should see Google in the search engines listing now.

[image]

**References**

[Make Google your default search engine](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/464?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmicrosoft-edge)

[Microsoft Edge - Set Google as the Default Search Engine](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/microsoft-edge-set-google-default-search-engine/)